# Google App Script returns null instead of inserting variable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, redirect

This is the email that gets sent from the script below.
[Approve or Deny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzNN5.png)

When I receive the approve or deny email and click deny this is the URL it takes me to.

```
http://null/?i=08a34673-a8f6-44bd-9fb2-916f17dc6c5a&state=DENIED
```

When it should be

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx7=C_AyyjTVtVl0mFXAlsv7Fh/exec?i=08a34673-a8f6-44bd-9fb2-916f17dc6c5a&state=DENIED
```

I am unsure what I am doing wrong?

Here is the function. The full script that I am referencing is [Request and approve time off Apps Script Enhancement](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y6x90S_q_cwdl4LGVDDSqMyuikx1zmPFyVQfSlYsKLk/edit)

```
function SheetHandler(sheet) {
  var _sheet = sheet;
  var _data = getRowsData(_sheet);
  
  var _markPending = function(d) {
    
    d.state = PENDING_STATE;
    d.identifier = Utils.generateUUID();
    
    manager_email = d[SETTINGS.MANAGERS_EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME].match(EMAIL_REGEX);
    
    var ScriptUri = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx7=C_AyyjTVtVl0mFXAlsv7Fh/exec';
    // hack some values on to the data just for email templates.
    d.approval_url = ScriptUri + "?i=" + d.identifier + '&state=' + APPROVED_STATE;
    d.deny_url = ScriptUri + "?i=" + d.identifier + '&state=' + DENIED_STATE;
    d.manager_email = manager_email

    message = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.PENDING_MANAGER_EMAIL, d);
    subject = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.PENDING_MANAGER_EMAIL_SUBJECT, d);
    
    MailApp.sendEmail(manager_email,subject,"",{ htmlBody: message });
    
    setRowData(_sheet, d);
  }
  
  var _getDataByKey = function(k) {
    row = undefined;
    _data.forEach(function(d) {
      if (d.identifier == k) {
        row = d;
      }
    });
    return row;
  }
  
  var processSheet = function() {
    _data.forEach(function(d) {
      if(d.state == BLANK_STATE) {
        _markPending(d);
      }
    });
  }
  
  var _createCalendarEventForDataRow = function(d) {
    // default to the user's calendar, unless we figure out other wise.
    var calendarId = d.emailAddress;
    var guests = new Array();
    
    if (SETTINGS.WRITE_TO_GROUP_CALENDAR == 1) {
      // The group calendar owns the event, invite the user.
      var calendarId = SETTINGS.GROUP_CALENDAR_ID;
      guests.push(d.emailAddress);
    }
    
    if (SETTINGS.INVITE_MANAGER_TO_EVENT == 1) {
      // Regardless of where the event is, invite the manager if requested.
      guests.push(d.actor);
    }
    
    var title = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.CALENDAR_EVENT_TITLE, d);
    var description = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.CALENDAR_EVENT_DESCRIPTION, d);
    var location = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.CALENDAR_EVENT_LOCATION, d);
    
    // Create a recurring daily event.
    var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
    Logger.log(calendarId);
    Logger.log(calendar.getName());
    var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().until(new Date(d.lastDayOfLeave));
    event = calendar.createAllDayEventSeries(title, new Date(d.leaveStartDate), recurrence, {
      description: description,
      sendInvites: false,
      location: location,
      guests: guests.join()
    });
    Logger.log(event.getId());
  }
  
  var approveByKey = function(k, user) {
    var d = _getDataByKey(k);
    d.state = APPROVED_STATE;
    d.actor = user;
    
    var message = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.USER_APPROVAL_EMAIL, d);
    var subject = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.USER_APPROVAL_EMAIL_SUBJECT, d);
    MailApp.sendEmail(d.emailAddress,subject,"",{ htmlBody: message });
    
    if(SETTINGS.SEND_APPROVAL_NOTICE_EMAIL == 1) {
      var message = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.APPROVAL_NOTICE_EMAIL, d);
      var subject = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.APPROVAL_NOTICE_EMAIL_SUBJECT, d);
      MailApp.sendEmail(SETTINGS.APPROVAL_NOTICE_EMAIL_TO, subject, "",{ htmlBody: message });
    }
    
    Logger.log(SETTINGS);
    if (SETTINGS.CREATE_CALENDAR_EVENT == 1) {
      Logger.log("Creating Calendar Event");
      _createCalendarEventForDataRow(d);
    }
    
    setRowData(_sheet, d);
  }
  
  var denyByKey = function(k, user) {
    var d = _getDataByKey(k);
    d.state = DENIED_STATE;
    d.actor = user;
    
    message = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.USER_DENIED_EMAIL, d);
    subject = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.USER_DENIED_EMAIL_SUBJECT, d);
    MailApp.sendEmail(d.emailAddress, subject, "",{ htmlBody: message });
    
    setRowData(_sheet, d);
  }

  return {
    'processSheet': processSheet,
    'approveByKey': approveByKey,
    'denyByKey': denyByKey
  }
};
```

Comment: I think that in your situation, it is required to know the value of `message`. When you checked this value, what result did you obtain? If you checked it when the URL has already been `http://null/?i=08a34673-a8f6-44bd-9fb2-916f17dc6c5a&state=DENIED`, I think that it is required to know the detail of `SETTINGS.PENDING_MANAGER_EMAIL`, `d` and `Utils.processTemplate()`.

Comment: If I change ScriptUri from `d.approval_url = ScriptUri` to `d.approval_url = 'https://www.google.com'` it still gives me null

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.